# What are the most common mistakes in developing Spring applications?

Tags: java, spring, testing, applicationcontext, automated-tests

I'm currently preparing my Bachelor thesis at the University of Münster. I plan to automatically identify typical problems in Spring configurations. There are a lot of tools at the market which perform static code analysis to find bugs or problems. These obviously can't detect problems which only appear at runtime. I'm going to analyse the ApplicationContext of a Spring application and find misconfiguration by using reflection and the analysis of the bean graph.

**Example:**
A simple example is, if somebody wants to make a class or method transaction secure by using annotations. He will normally add a @Transactional-tag above the class or method, but if the application isn't configured right and there is no transaction manager registered to the ApplicationContext, which observes annotations, then the tag will be ignored. No error message will arise, which is the reason that these types of problems are hard to find so far.

**Question:**
Which are the most common mistakes or architectural faults caused by misconfiguration using the spring mechanisms, which can be detected by a dynamic analysis? Are there any projects which attend to do something similar?

*P.S.* In the course of my thesis I will develop a prototype which can detect these kinds of problems and open source it henceforth. :)

Comment: Cool project, not very relevant as a question in SO, imo. `component-scan`-ing comes to mind as something that I miss or do incorrectly some times, but it's hard to tell what are the true expected packages.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Do you know any other platform, where this question could fit better?

Comment: Perhaps [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

From the Spring related questions I have answerd, your Example (not correct initialized @Transaction) is one of the most asked Problems. But with a small tweek: Often the Problem is that somebody tryes this:

```
@Service
public class SomeService() {

  @Transaction
  public void save(Some thing) {
      ...
  }

  public void doSomeThing(Some thing) {
     ...
     this.save(thing);
  }
}
```

And then they are wondering why the `@Transactional` annotation is not taken in account when using `doSomeThing`.

The problem is that this works only this real AspectJ and not with this Proxy AOP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with your described constellation is, that I additionally have to a static code analysis, beneath the dynamic analysis of the ApplicationContext. Or do you see any other approach?

Comment: @a.ha Yes: you need some static code analysis to detect the invocations of the method.